# SELECT statement against identical dbs giving different results

Tags: mysql

I have a live and development database that are identical.

When doing the following SELECT statement against each DB, I get different results.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (TIME_TO_SEC(c.duration) BETWEEN 0 AND 30) THEN '00:00:00 - 00:00:30'
WHEN (TIME_TO_SEC(c.duration) BETWEEN 31 AND 60) THEN '00:00:31 - 00:01:00'
WHEN (TIME_TO_SEC(c.duration) BETWEEN 61 AND 90) THEN '00:01:01 - 00:01:30'
WHEN (TIME_TO_SEC(c.duration) BETWEEN 91 AND 120) THEN '00:01:31 - 00:02:00'
WHEN (TIME_TO_SEC(c.duration) BETWEEN 121 AND 180) THEN '00:02:01 - 00:03:00'
WHEN (TIME_TO_SEC(c.duration) BETWEEN 181 AND 240) THEN '00:03:01 - 00:04:00'
WHEN (TIME_TO_SEC(c.duration) BETWEEN 241 AND 300) THEN '00:04:01 - 00:05:00'
WHEN (TIME_TO_SEC(c.duration) BETWEEN 301 AND 420) THEN '00:05:01 - 00:07:00'
WHEN (TIME_TO_SEC(c.duration) BETWEEN 421 AND 600) THEN '00:07:01 - 00:10:00'
ELSE 'Over 00:10:00'
END AS 'time_period',
COUNT(c.id) AS 'call_usage',
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(c.duration))) AS 'total_duration',
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(c.duration)) / TIME_TO_SEC('838:59:59') AS 'percent_total'
FROM       call_detail c
INNER JOIN credit_unions cu ON c.credit_union_id = cu.id
WHERE      cu.abbreviation = 'REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY'
AND        c.call_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND DATE_ADD('2013-01-31', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY   'time_period'
ORDER BY   'time_period' ASC
```

The live DB gives me the following results, which are the correct results.

```
time_period call_usage  total_duration  percent_total
"00:00:00 - 00:00:30"   12033   83:01:42    0.0990
"00:00:31 - 00:01:00"   22947   291:34:48   0.3475
"00:01:01 - 00:01:30"   11137   236:53:24   0.2823
"00:01:31 - 00:02:00"   5904    175:13:54   0.2089
"00:02:01 - 00:03:00"   5970    247:05:24   0.2945
"00:03:01 - 00:04:00"   2591    150:58:54   0.1800
"00:04:01 - 00:05:00"   1359    101:49:24   0.1214
"00:05:01 - 00:07:00"   1197    116:25:36   0.1388
"00:07:01 - 00:10:00"   481     65:48:24    0.0784
"Over 00:10:00"         192     42:22:24    0.0505
```

The development DB gives me the following results, which are incorrect.

```
time_period call_usage  total_duration  percent_total
"00:00:31 - 00:01:00"   63811   858:59:59   1.8012
```

I can't figure out why/how this is happening.

Comment: Are both databases running on the same server, the same DB instance? Do you use the same tool to connect to both instances?

Comment: Remove the group by and the count (and the 2 SUMs) and try it again to see what it is bringing back for the time_period field.

Comment: The DBs are on different servers.  The live DB was exported and imported into the dev DB.  I am using MySQL Workbench to connect to both servers to do the SQL query.

I removed the group, count, and the 2 SUMs.  Same results as before.

Comment: Did you remove the SUM from both the `total_duration` and `percent_total` (along with the `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`)?  If so, the query should return 1 record for each input row, and look a lot different than the grouped results.  Could you display 20 lines or so when you do this?

Comment: I messed up the first time I edited the select statement.  The second time around, after removing the SUM from the total_duration and percent_total, along with the COUNT and GROUP BY, I get 63,811 rows returned on both the live and dev DB.

Comment: Actually, ORDER BY 'time_period' ASC didn't work on the dev DB.  It is not ordered by the time_period.  Appears to be in random order.  It is ordered by the time_period on the live DB though.

Comment: Can you post the data structure and some of the exported data so we can see it. Generally no reason it shouldn't order by date unless the date has been corrupted on export / import.